# Nexus 6P wifi only 1/10th of Laptop

Tags: networking, router, wireless-router

I have a [Nexus 6P](http://www.gsmarena.com/huawei_nexus_6p-7588.php) which is a fairly new phone and supports the following wifi bands: Wi-Fi 802.11 a/b/g/n/ac. When I do a speed test on my phone I get 9 megabits/s (Mbps). When I run a speed test on my 2014 Macbook Pro running Sierra it gets around 90 Mbps. Why is that?

They're both using wifi. The wireless router is right under the table that both the laptop and phone are on and it's just a wooden table. So I can't see physical objects interfering the network. The phone itself is fine. When I disconnect from the wifi it uses 4G LTE and gets 80 Mbps.

I have an [Asus RT-N66U router](https://www.asus.com/au/Networking/RTN66U/).

What are possible issues and how can I start diagnosing the cause?

Answer (score 0):

## The Router

**Does your router support IEEE 802.11ac?** Since your laptop gets around 90 Mbps the router supports *at least IEEE 802.11n*. Try connecting to a local network resource and measure the speed as there might be limitations set by your Internet Service Provide.

You should have the option to specify different SSIDs (wireless network names) for the different bands (2.4 GHz and 5 GHz) which will enable you to manually pick the band your devices are using. You should also have the option to ***disable IEEE 802.11a and IEEE 802.11b*** to ensure those standards aren't used. *Disabling 802.11b* will also give your entire network a performance boost.

## Wi-Fi Band

Check which Wi-Fi band is being used by your phone. Is it 2.4 GHz or 5 GHz?

### 2.4 GHz Band

The 2.4 GHz is used by the IEEE 802.11 standards **b/g/n**. It's good at penetrating thick things like walls but is prone to interference from e.g. other wireless networks (incl. Bluetooth) and even microwave ovens.

*It's better to have multiple 5 GHz access points if that's possible. Myself I only have 5 GHz access points set to low power so they only cover 1 room each. 2.4 GHz can be used for larger areas but if there aren't many 2.4 GHz networks nearby it's safe and fast to use.*

### 5 GHz Band

The 5 GHz band is used by the IEEE 802.11 standards **a/n/ac**. It's high performance and not prone to interference. It's good at short distances and will loose a lot of strength passing just one wall. You can have a lot of 5 GHz networks in the same area without interference.

## IEEE 802.11 Standards

Check which IEEE 802.11 standard is used by your phone to connect to the wireless access point. a/b/g are very slow while n/ac is fast. IEEE 802.11 a/n/ac are good for short range and are interference free while b/g/n are good for long range but are prone to interference.

### IEEE 802.11a/b/g

There standard are the oldest one and are supported by almost any device and also a bit **slow**. 802.11a uses the 5 GHz network while 802.11b/g uses the **2.4 GHz** band. 802.11a and is good to use close to the router and there is almost no interference while 802.11b/g have a lot of interference but good range.

### IEEE 802.11n/ac

These are the newest ones and are supported by almost any new device. **802.11n** is dual-band, meaning it can use both the 2.4 GHz band *and* the 5 GHz band *, depending on device support*. The **802.11ac** standard is only using the **5 GHz band** which limits the range but is interference free and also very **fast**.